# checkbox in angular-ui tab's header

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using AngularUI's bootstrap library 0.4.0. I want to make a tabset that has checkable header, [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/blInCVq4ppWa5rwnJYRR). However, as you can see, I cannot check the checkbox at all. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have figured out a solution, although it may seem a bit hacky.

in the checkbox, I add an extra ng-click attribute to become

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="stopPropagation($event)"/>
```

According to AngularJS documentation, $event has the event object of the action, here is click. So if we can stop the propagation of the event, we can check the checkbox. In the controller, I add a method stopPropagation as below

```
$scope.stopPropagation = function(e) {
    // to make sure it is a checkbox
    if (angular.element(e.currentTarget).prop('tagName') === 'INPUT') {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

This is the
[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YOSgJGCLtYvnOjlcK1R8?p=preview)

Comment: Worth mentioning that this approach also works for accordions - where you have a checkbox present in the accordion heading.